# Choosing the inner of two possible matches

Tags: regex

I want to make a match in the following string:

```
' return 0\r\nConnection to 172.29.28.79 closed by remote host.\r\r\nConnection to 172.29.28.79 closed.\r\r\n'
```

The goal of the match is `Connection to 172.29.28.79 closed.` The problems are that the IP adress might change to any meaningful host address. A simple match to `Connection .* closed\.` will yield a result that contains both sentences, which is undesired.

How to write a meaningful regex that matches just the *one sentence* that starts with `Connection`, ends with `closed.` and has something in the middle whch I don't care about?

Comment: This is a FAQ. Read about greedy and non-greedy matching.

Comment: This would let me choose between the first or both sentences. I want to just match the second, though.

Comment: Use `.*` at the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be more specific in your regexp. Since an IP can't contain spaces, you can write:

```
Connection to [^ ]* closed\.
```

The escaped `.` will prevent it from matching `closed by remote host` -- it will only match `closed.`

Comment: True. I don't care about the `to`, but if it's there, why not match it. I seem to think too complicated sometimes.

Comment: I am matching the `to`.

Comment: Yes, you do. But before your post I didn't even think about that simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lokahead here.

```
Connection.+?closed\.(?=[\n\r]|$)
```

This regex checks that the charcters which are following the string `closed` must be a `.` and a `\n` (*newline character*) or `\r` (*carriage return*) or `$`(End of the line.)

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/6)

Comment: A positive lookahead to make sure it's the last message. That's nice.

Comment: @erik So does `.*` at the beginning of the expression. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex would be `Connection\sto\s(.+?)\sclosed\.`.
[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Qjvcyp2idt),
[Visual explanation](http://www.regexper.com/#Connection%5Csto%5Cs(.%2B%3F)%5Csclosed)

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex (tested in C#)?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Connection to \d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3} closed\.");
Match match = regex.Match(str);
```

This regex also looks for the IP address format, so that in case you have a line such as "Connection to www.example.com closed.", that line is not matched.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SRSN21799)

Comment: What's the difference? Does it really just match the second sentence?

Comment: Yes it does. The slash before the last dot matches the dot character.